# Expo eas react-native app submit gets "SwiftSupport folder is missing" error

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo

I have an expo react native app.  When I use

```
eas build --non-interactive -p all --auto-submit-with-profile development
```

All goes well.  Both ios and android apps are built and submitted.  It took me a long time to get there!

But I get an email back from apple that says:

```
ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
```

This is an expo react-native app so I do not have a SwiftSupport folder.

This is my eas.json file:

```
{
  "cli": { "requireCommit": true },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "node": "12.22.8"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "node": "12.22.8"
    },
    "production": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "node": "12.22.8"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "development": {
      "android": {
        "serviceAccountKeyPath": "./private/google-app-service-account.json",
        "track": "internal"
      },
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "uuu@uuuuuu.uuu",
        "ascAppId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "appleTeamId": "yyyyyyyyyy"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "serviceAccountKeyPath": "./private/google-app-service-account.json",
        "track": "internal"
      },
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "uuu@uuuuuu.uuu",
        "ascAppId": "aaaaaaaaaa",
        "appleTeamId": "bbbbbbbbbb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have reprovisioned (I think) and generated a new set of credentials and still no go.

I used this command to reprovision:

```
 expo build:ios -c
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am using the latest (non-beta) xcode - 13.2.1. And it happens whether I build on my local machine or using a github action.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?  same problem here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is you are building with

```
"distribution": "internal"
```

Which they are not meant to get published to ios. If you remove that it should work.

Comment: OMG that did it!  Weeks I've been working on this.  Thanks!

Comment: This also solves the missing builds during `eas submit`. Now I'm able to choose it using the "Select a build from EAS" option